# Puppeteer not working in google cloud functions

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, puppeteer

Puppeteer isn't working in google cloud!

That chrome error is in the picture.

[image]

I already implemented the suggestion here: [Puppeteer error on Heroku: Could not find Chromium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74385208/puppeteer-error-on-heroku-could-not-find-chromium)

I also tried to downgrade my puppeteer version from 19.x to 18.x and 17.x but no luck.

I'll try using Playwright unless someone here has an idea of how to fix this...

**EDIT:** I've tried using puppeteer-chromium-resolver instead of puppeteer however now I am entirely unable to deploy my cloud function on node runtime 16 and 18.

**EDIT 2:** I've abandoned puppeteer-chromium-resolver in favor of chrome-aws-lambda and have added the following code snippet and deployed to Google cloud functions:

```
const bundledChromium = require('chrome-aws-lambda');
const playwright = require('playwright-core');

(async () => {
    const browser = await Promise.resolve(bundledChromium.executablePath).then(
    (executablePath) => {
      console.log("executablePath: ", executablePath);
      if (!executablePath) {
        // local execution
        return playwright.chromium.launch({});
      }
      return playwright.chromium.launch({ executablePath });
    }
  );
})()
```

the statement `console.log("executablePath: ", executablePath);` prints "/tmp/chromium"

however I get another error:

```
2022-12-27 15:12:00.281 HKT
function-1ol6uqbjimrh1 Function execution started
2022-12-27 15:12:00.295 HKT
function-1ol6uqbjimrh1 executablePath: /tmp/chromium
2022-12-27 15:12:00.305 HKT
function-1ol6uqbjimrh1 Function execution took 24 ms, finished with status: 'ok'
2022-12-27 15:12:00.414 HKT
function-1ol6uqbjimrh1 browserType.launch: spawn EFAULT
2022-12-27 15:12:00.414 HKT
function-1ol6uqbjimrh1 =========================== logs ===========================
2022-12-27 15:12:00.414 HKT
function-1ol6uqbjimrh1 <launching> /tmp/chromium --disable-field-trial-config --disable-background-networking --enable-features=NetworkService,NetworkServiceInProcess --disable-background-timer-throttling --disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows --disable-back-forward-cache --disable-breakpad --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-component-extensions-with-background-pages --disable-component-update --no-default-browser-check --disable-default-apps --disable-dev-shm-usage --disable-extensions --disable-features=ImprovedCookieControls,LazyFrameLoading,GlobalMediaControls,DestroyProfileOnBrowserClose,MediaRouter,DialMediaRouteProvider,AcceptCHFrame,AutoExpandDetailsElement,CertificateTransparencyComponentUpdater,AvoidUnnecessaryBeforeUnloadCheckSync,Translate --allow-pre-commit-input --disable-hang-monitor --disable-ipc-flooding-protection --disable-popup-blocking --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-renderer-backgrounding --disable-sync --force-color-profile=srgb --metrics-recording-only --no-first-run --enable-automation --password-store=basic --use-mock-keychain --no-service-autorun --export-tagged-pdf --headless --hide-scrollbars --mute-audio --blink-settings=primaryHoverType=2,availableHoverTypes=2,primaryPointerType=4,availablePointerTypes=4 --no-sandbox --user-data-dir=/tmp/playwright_chromiumdev_profile-K9OYeC --remote-debugging-pipe --no-startup-window
2022-12-27 15:12:00.414 HKT
function-1ol6uqbjimrh1 ============================================================
2022-12-27 15:12:00.414 HKT
function-1ol6uqbjimrh1 at /workspace/index.js:37:25
2022-12-27 15:12:00.414 HKT
function-1ol6uqbjimrh1 at async main (/workspace/index.js:30:21) {
2022-12-27 15:12:00.414 HKT
function-1ol6uqbjimrh1 name: 'Error'
2022-12-27 15:12:00.414 HKT
function-1ol6uqbjimrh1 }
```

Not sure how to proceed from here...

**FINAL EDIT:** I tried using AWS lambda with puppeteer in ECR and that didn't work either so I am using python selenium on pythonanywhere.com. This whole experience has been frustrating but at least selenium works.

Here's a link to a github for further details: https://github.com/Sparticuz/chromium/issues/29

Comment: Please no [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Did you search for similar posts like [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74362083/cloud-functions-puppeteer-cannot-open-browser), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61930743/puppeteer-not-working-with-google-cloud-functions-in-node-10-runtime), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61986633/puppeteer-launch-in-cloud-functions-throwing-error), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74769348/firebase-function-puppeteer-could-not-find-chromium-gcp)?

Comment: none of those work

Comment: Did you try the https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-chromium-resolver? Please provide more details of all the things you tried as an [edit] to the post, with as complete information as possible (package.json, environment settings, code, other config details, all relevant logs and errors in text format, etc). Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. However, now the deployment itself is failing.

Comment: What error are you seeing, please?

Comment: `Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code.` But I know it isn't the code as I am running it locally first.

Comment: OK, thanks, but we're still missing the code, a package.json and a [mcve]. It's really hard to help just by guessing what your environment, version and code might be.

Comment: I've added a code example.

Answer (score 5):

### 1. Add `.puppeteerrc.cjs` and change default cache directory.

```
const { join } = require("path");

/**
 * @type {import("puppeteer").Configuration}
 */
module.exports = {
  // Changes the cache location for Puppeteer.
  cacheDirectory: join(__dirname, ".cache", "puppeteer"),
};
```

### 2. After you add `.puppeteerrc.cjs`, puppeteer package has to be re-installed, so you have to delete your function from GCP, and re-deploy your function.

### 3. Chrome will be installed within your source dir, puppeteer now can find right path for chrome.

Comment: As i am still having the same issue as the OP I gave the suggestion a try. I am using firebase Functions and installed "puppeteer": "^20.5.0", added .puppeteerrc.cjs with the recommended code. but this seems to trigger another type of error : Error: HTTP Error: 400, <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>EntityTooLarge</Code><Message>Your proposed upload is larger than the
maximum object size specified in your Policy Document.</Message><Details>Content-length exceeds upper bound on range</Details></Error>
PS D:\*\functions>

Comment: "You have to delete your function from GCP, and re-deploy your function." Was what worked for us.

Comment: @Bliv_Dev It beacuse now you have a .CACHE file with the puppeteer installation that you must delete from your local files.
To me it added more than 200MB to my deployment size...

Answer (score 0):

I am adding this answer because I drove myself nuts with this all day and followed everything online and what worked for me in the end was the following.

1. I added "gcp-deploy":"npm install puppeteer" for the initial deploy (no cloud function must exist)
2. I removed this for subsequent deployments because otherwise it wouldnt work.
3. I do have the .puppeteerrc.cjs file with the identical content as mentioned above.
4. I didn't have the one that was supposed to install from the node_module/puppeteer folder.

Maybe this helps someone. It was what worked for me, so your mileage may vary.